# Add property to option with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an onclick event:

```
<button class="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "<?php echo $this->result[$i]["ctype"]; ?>", "<?php echo htmlentities($this->result[$i]["name"], ENT_QUOTES); ?>", "<?php echo $quality; ?>", "<?php echo $this->result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>", "<?php echo $status; ?>",...)'></button>
```

I pass these to jquery and build a form (in a modal dialog):

```
var edit = function(t, ctype, name, quality, hash, status, ...)
 {

    var $formDiv = jQuery("#editform");
    $formDiv.empty();

    var $editForm = jQuery("<form id='EditForm' method='post'></form>");
....//more code on building form
    var $selectStatus = jQuery("<select id='Status' name='camera_status'></select>");

    var enabledHtml = "<option value='ENABLED'>ON</option>";
    var disabledHtml = "<option value='DISABLED'>OFF</option>";

    var $statusEnabled = jQuery(enabledHtml);
    var $statusDisabled = jQuery(disabledHtml);

    // create opt group
    var $optgroup = jQuery("<optgroup label='Info'>");
    if(info.length > 0){   
        for (i=0; i<info.length; i++) {
            var $op = jQuery("<option value='" + info[i].info_hash + "'>" + info[i].info_name + "</option>");
            $optgroup.append($op);
        }
    }else{
        var op = "<option value='none' disabled>None</option>";
        $optgroup.append(op);
    }
```

Where `info` is:

```
var info = [{"info_name":"test","info_hash":"3029688965"},{"info_name":"gggg","info_hash":"175360653"},...]
```

This works great. My problem is the select and making a default selection. I pass in the variable `status`  to help with that. This has a value of 0 (off), 1 (on) or a string name which is under the optgroup.

So this code here works great for the on/off property:

```
if (status == 1) {
    $statusEnabled.prop("selected", "selected");
}
else if (status == 0){
    $statusDisabled.prop("selected", "selected");
}
else {

    console.log(status);
}

$selectStatus.append($statusEnabled, $statusDisabled, $optgroup);
```

In the else block the console.log shows me the right value. I guess I'm just stuck figuring how I can assign a "selected" value in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should navigate through the `<option>`s tags, and if one of them matches the name, assign a `selected` property:

```
if (status == 1) {
    $statusEnabled.prop("selected", "selected");
}
else if (status == 0){
    $statusDisabled.prop("selected", "selected");
}
else {
    $selectStatus.each(function() {
        if($(this).html() == status)
            $(this).prop("selected", true);
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

You may set the selected property in the creation of the options:

```
for (i=0; i<info.length; i++) {
    var $op = jQuery("<option value='" + info[i].info_hash + "'>" + info[i].info_name + "</option>");
    if(info[i].info_name == status)
        $op.prop("selected", true);
    $optgroup.append($op);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I never seem to get into the each function. Something wrong with the selector? It is `Status` so I tried `$("#Status option").each(function()`...no luck

Comment: Is the `<select>` already added to the page at the moment this part of the code runs?

Comment: Hmm that's right I don't add it until later `$editForm.append($labelStatus, $selectStatus, ....);`. I tried to move that code around but no luck...

Comment: Closer. Now the problem is the if statement doesn't get evaluated `if($(this).html() == status)`. Seems this `$(this).html()` is empty.

Comment: Let me ask you... Do you already have the `status` value at the moment of creation of the select?

Comment: Yes you have that value. I updated post with more context...hope this helps. Much appreciated.